# Changing an animation variable with manipulate and button

Tags: manipulate, animation, button, rotation

I need Manipulate to add buttons. And I think I need Dynamic somewhere. I tried searching in the stackexchange for anything similar because I feel that surely someone has also this in mind. Many of almost similar question/answer look way more complicated than I expected. So I decide to post the question here.

The code is the following, it illustrates some representative permutations in $S_4$ by thinking of permutation of a cubes long diagonals by rotations of them about the origin:

```
g=Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Cuboid[{-5, -5, -5}, {5, 5, 5}], 
  Opacity[1.0], Thick, Green, Line[{{-5, -5, -5}, {5, 5, 5}}], 
  Line[{{5, -5, -5}, {-5, 5, 5}}], Line[{{-5, 5, -5}, {5, -5, 5}}], 
  Line[{{-5, -5, 5}, {5, 5, -5}}], Black, 
  Text[Style[1, Large, Bold, Red], {5, 5, 5}],
  Text[Style[2, Large, Bold, Red], {5, -5, 5}],
  Text[Style[3, Large, Bold, Red], {-5, 5, 5}],
  Text[Style[4, Large, Bold, Red], {-5, -5, 5}]}];

Manipulate[
 MapAt[Rotate[#, t, v, {0, 0, 0}] &, g, {1}], {t, 0, T, 
  ControlType -> Animator, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward, 
  AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False}, 
 Button["Transposition(1,3)",{v, T}={{0, 5, 5}, Pi}], 
 Button["3-Cycle (2,3,4)",{v, T}={{5, 5, 5}, 2 Pi/3}], 
 Button["4-Cycle", {v, T}={{0, 0, 1}, Pi/2}], 
 Button["2 Transp.", {v, T}={{0, 0, 1}, Pi}], 
 Initialization :> {{v, T}={{0, 5, 5}, Pi}}]
```

I am missing something here. Because the effect doesn't look like what I wanted. I feel like I have to use `Dynamic` somewhere (and I am not well versed enough with Dynamic to know exactly how this is done), since the variables `{v,T}` do not change properly. After pressing on one of the button esp. the 3-cycle button, I am almost sure that changes are wrong (although the animation becomes different). Any ideas here? If this matters.. I use Mathematica 10.0.1.0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say: "the effect doesn't look like what I want". Please tell us very clearly what you want to happen, because how can we know what it is supposed to look like?

Comment: The "effect" should be that once a button is pressed and play button is pressed (force the animation direction to only be Forward instead of BackwardForward to see this). The final position of the cube after 1 animation cycle will not be skewed but will be exactly the same position as the original at time = 0. The only change will be that the big diagonals 1,2,3 and 4 are permuted. All the axes of rotation and rotation angle changes (from the button) ensure this.

Comment: Maybe change the duration of the animation? For the first one, change `Pi` to `2 Pi`.